# How to group toolbar items in iOS project?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

in many iOS projects you can see toolbar items that are grouped like this

[image]

As you can see the arrows are grouped. Any idea how to achieve this by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can put anything (any View) in UIToolbar. Every UIBarButtonItem has a property "customView". Just set the customView any view you want. In this case it's a UISegmentedControl. You can also simply drag out an UISegmentedControl onto your UIToolbar in Interface Builder.

Comment: Although UISegmentedControl is not behave like a normal UIBarButtonItem. But it looks the same. And you just need a little tweak to make the UISegmentedControl behave like a normal UIBarButtonItem.